# All icons are broken

Tags: bug, status-completed

[image]

All my icons for network questions apear as the little 3D icon...? Is anyone else having this problem?

Seems like this is not a problem just with the IoT beta (May have been caused by it?)

because it seems to have happened everywhere[image]

Comment: Related to: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277518/all-stack-exchange-site-logos-are-showing-up-as-the-3d-printing-one

Comment: Recent report on Meta.SE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287844/164356

Comment: I was having the same issue, but it's fixed now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[All Stack Exchange site logos are showing up as the 3D Printing one REDUX](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/287848/164356):

> I actually managed to screw this up in a new and exciting way as we moved favicon generation around. Due to caching on dev, we missed it. It was a grep for favicon.less, but turns out our base .less includes it via: @import "favicons/favicons", which didn't show up in my grep of "places to fix".
>
> A fix is building out now.
>
> *-- Nick Craver ♦*